# Repeated ImageView on ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-imageview

My ImageView keep repeated on ListView every 6 items
here my code for CustomAdapter

```
public class NewsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<NewsContainer> {

private Context context;
private NewsContainer[] newsContainer;

public NewsAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceID, NewsContainer[] newsContainers) {
    super(context, textViewResourceID, newsContainers);
    this.newsContainer = newsContainers;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position){
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent){
    viewHolder holder = null;
    if(view == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_listview, null);

        holder = new viewHolder();
        holder.image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        holder.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        holder.created_date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.created_date);
        holder.category = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.category);
        holder.post_count = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.post_count);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (viewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    NewsContainer news = newsContainer[position];
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("DD/MM/yyyy", Locale.US);
    if(news != null){
        String date = format.format(news.getCreatedDate());
        holder.title.setText(news.getTitle());
        holder.post_count.setText(String.valueOf(news.getPostCount()));
        holder.created_date.setText(date);
        holder.category.setText(Html.fromHtml(news.getCategory()));
        if(!news.getThumbnail().equals("empty")){
            new ImageDownloaderTask(holder.image).execute(news.getThumbnail());
        }    
    }

    return view;
}

static class viewHolder {
    ImageView image;
    TextView title;
    TextView created_date;
    TextView category;
    TextView post_count;
}
```

ImageDownloader class

```
public class ImageDownloaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewWeakReference;

public ImageDownloaderTask(ImageView imageView) {
    this.imageViewWeakReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
}

@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
    return downloadBitmap(params[0]);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap){
    if(isCancelled()){
        bitmap = null;
    }

    if(imageViewWeakReference != null){
        ImageView imageView = imageViewWeakReference.get();
        if(imageView != null){
            if(bitmap != null){
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } else {
                imageView.setImageDrawable(imageView.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_loading_image));
            }
        }
    }
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO)
static Bitmap downloadBitmap(String url) {
    final AndroidHttpClient client = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("Android");
    final HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);
    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);
        final int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            Log.w("ImageDownloader", "Error " + statusCode
                    + " while retrieving bitmap from " + url);
            return null;
        }

        final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if (entity != null) {
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            try {
                inputStream = entity.getContent();
                final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                return bitmap;
            } finally {
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    inputStream.close();
                }
                entity.consumeContent();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Could provide a more explicit error message for IOException or
        // IllegalStateException
        getRequest.abort();
        Log.w("ImageDownloader", "Error while retrieving bitmap from " + url);
    } finally {
        if (client != null) {
            client.close();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I have tried using ViewHolder but the ImageView keeps repeat, and found that the ListView recycles its view in order to keep the memory occupation low. but i can't understand how to solve this problem.

Comment: does overriding getCount() method in your adapter helps? Here you essentially return newsContainer.size();

Answer (score 3):

```
else {
    holder = (viewHolder) view.getTag();
}
```

Here is your real problem, you are inflating in case `view` is null but not doing any modifications in case it already has a value. When the `view` is being recycled it will contain some value and won't be null. So you have to change all the values instead of reusing the existing ones.

Comment: thank you very much, it is what i was looking for. I fixed this problem adding a sentence changer holder.image to the default value.

Comment: @danigonlinea i am facing exact same issue, can u share the code line that u fixed for this ? thanks

Comment: @k2ibegin simple logic will help you solve your problem. When you start scrolling, the view that goes out of screen from one side is returned as a parameter in getview while fetching view for the other side. This is the exact same view, so if you don't change the content.. it will show you old one only. Change the content using a holder.

Comment: @k2ibegin Just reset image in the 'else' block with this holder.image_item.setImageDrawable(null); and avoid to reusing the existings ones.

Comment: @danigonlinea sorry for the late answer, i got stuck with other issues. I tried that but now it just removes my images everywhere, for example where ever i was seeing image repeated, those places are shown as null, resulting into my actual images also getting whitewashed ! Is there a specific way to reset the previous image holders ? However, i guess after resetting holder image view, if user scrolls back up then those images will not be there ?

Answer (score 2):

You should clear or reset the image view if you get an empty thumbnail in `getView`.

Writing from my phone, apologies for the brevity.

Edit: I don't see that you've set this in your code at all. Where you have for instance:

```
if(news != null){
    String date = format.format(news.getCreatedDate());
    holder.title.setText(news.getTitle());
    holder.post_count.setText(String.valueOf(news.getPostCount()));
    holder.created_date.setText(date);
    holder.category.setText(Html.fromHtml(news.getCategory()));
    if(!news.getThumbnail().equals("empty")){
        new ImageDownloaderTask(holder.image).execute(news.getThumbnail());
    }    
}
```

what if `news` is null or `news.getThumbnail().equals("empty") == true`? You will be leaving a recycled image view unchanged.

Comment: i have setup code for add default image when the image is empty, but still get the same result

Comment: @Randy I still don't see that you're always clearing out an old image. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent){

 if(view == null){
      LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_listview, null);
  }

    ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
    TextView  title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
    TextView  created_date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.created_date);
    TextView category = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.category);
    TextView post_count = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.post_count);

 NewsContainer news = NewsContainer[position];
 SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("DD/MM/yyyy", Locale.US);
 if(news != null){
     String date = format.format(news.getCreatedDate());
     title.setText(news.getTitle());
     post_count.setText(String.valueOf(news.getPostCount()));
     created_date.setText(date);
     category.setText(Html.fromHtml(news.getCategory()));
     if(!news.getThumbnail().equals("empty")){
        new ImageDownloaderTask(image).execute(news.getThumbnail());
  }    

}
```